# Use a non default hive metastore database name

Tags: hive, metastore

There are  two versions of hive on one machine. The intent is to support both by a single instance of mysql. In order to do so we would need to use a different database name than **metastore**

The following was added to the hive-conf.xml of the *second* hive instance: notice that the db name is **metastore14**, and that **createDatabaseIfNotExist** were set to true:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore14?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>
```

In addition we set the corresponding datanucleus-specific property:

```
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Also the HIVE_CONF_DIR is set correctly:

```
17:08:28/libexec $echo $HIVE_CONF_DIR
/usr/local/Cellar/hive/0.14.0/libexec/conf
```

However, when connecting to the hive14 from a hive client the following error occurs:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/0.14.0/libexec/lib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

-- run create table statement and get following error:

Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingTableException: 
Required table missing : "`VERSION`" in Catalog "" Schema "". DataNucleus
requires this table to perform its persistence operations. Either your 
MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.autoCreateTables"
```

What additional steps are required?